# Charging a battery with kinetic energy (rotating wheel)

Tags: batteries, charging

What would be a simple setup that would allow me to spin something kind of like a servo motor but would result in power that can be used to charge a battery when you spin it yourself.

Comment: Do you mean a dynamo?

Comment: Most motors will work as generators when driven by external force, this is how regenerative breaking works.

Comment: More infor -> better answers. Hoiw much energy required? What is sorce? What is load? What is situation overall? Bike wheel driven generators are widely available. Roll-your-own may be a good idea deep-ending on other factors. ebay is probably simplest path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is called a *generator*.  It is the reverse of a motor.  You turn the generator shaft and it produces electrical power.

The more tricky part is matching the power out of the generator to what will charge the battery without damaging it.  That's a much longer discussion with lots of tradeoffs.  At your apparent level, get a big enough and robust enough battery so that anything a small generator can put out won't damage it.  For example, anything you can crank with your hand can't put out enough power to hurt a car battery.

At the bare minimum, you need to put a diode (preferably a Schottky diode) between the generator and the battery so that the generator can only charge, not discharge, the battery.

Comment: Thanks! What should I look for to charge a 9V battery with the spin of a bike wheel?

Comment: @MarkLyons if you had specific requirements, why didn't you put them in your question?